# Android Facebook Get Complete User Profile

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am unable to get the complete user profile using the Facebook sdk. I am trying to retrieve the user node from the Facebook's graph API referring to the following link. I am only receiving a few fields(sort of a limited profile thingy)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

I first perform login using the following line.

```
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(getActivity(), Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
```

Once I have an access token, I call the "/me" endpoint. I get the Facebook user ID of the respective user. Using this ID,  I then call  the "/{user-id}" endpoint using the following bit of code.

```
   new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/" + userProfile.getId(),
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.getRawResponse());
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```

The fields returned however are limited and do not contain the complete set of fields mentioned in the link below.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

**How do i retrieve the complete set of data tied to a user, including the list of friends , age etc as mentioned in the above link?**

I am only able to retrieve 
*id,email ,first_name,gender,last_name,link,locale,name, timezone and verified fields*, currently.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to retrieve the required or specific fields. By default all fields from a particular node are not returned. You need to specify them by passing them as parameters as shown below.

```
GraphRequest graphRequest = new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.getRawResponse());


                }
            }
    );
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,email,first_name,gender,last_name,link,locale,name,timezone,updated_time,verified,age_range,friends");
    graphRequest.setParameters(parameters);
    graphRequest.executeAsync();
```